# what is the difference between Future<void> and void

Tags: flutter, dart, future, void, smartphone

I'm writing a code in flutter and don't know what is the difference between them

`    Future senddata(BluetoothDevice d) async {

```
 BluetoothConnection? connection;

connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(d.address);

connection.output.add(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode("irgendwas"))); 

await connection.output.allSent;

} `
```

Comment: Duplicated Question. Answer here: [Future<void> vs void](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59833075/4605422)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a method as Future you can await it
If you declared only as void you can't await

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qdx5.png)

A void method can be async, but it cannot be awaited.